# How to Set Up SDL2 using Eclipse ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, sdl

I've been trying to get SDL2 working with Eclipse on Ubuntu.

I have tried following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325293/using-sdl-in-eclipse), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561458/sdl-configuration-in-eclipse-ide), and [this](http://www.zxiiro.ca/2013/08/08/Setting-up-Eclipse-CDT-for-SDL2-development/) but I just cannot get it working.

How can I get SDL2 working with Eclipse and have everything properly linked together?

EDIT:
When ever I compile the program it comes back saying that SDL.h is missing or there is no such directory, even though i can see SDL in the includes from the project list.

When compiling i have tried using:

```
gcc SDLTest.cpp

g++ SDLTest.cpp

gcc -o test SDLTest.cpp `sdl-config --cflags --libs`
```

I'm unsure of the difference between using GCC or G++, and i got the third compile from [here.](http://When%20ever%20I%20compile%20the%20program%20it%20comes%20back%20saying%20that%20SDL.h%20is%20missing%20or%20there%20is%20no%20such%20directory,%20even%20though%20i%20can%20see%20SDL%20in%20the%20includes%20from%20the%20project%20list.%20%20When%20compiling%20i%20have%20tried%20using:%20%60gcc%20SDLTest.cpp%60%20%60g++%20SDLTest.cpp%60%20and%20%60gcc%20-o%20test%20SDLTest.cpp%20%60sdl-config%20--cflags%20--libs%60%20%20I'm%20unsure%20of%20the%20difference%20between%20using%20GCC%20or%20G++,%20and%20i%20got%20the%20third%20compile%20from%20[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837639/how-to-use-sdl-in-linux).)

I've added the SDL include folder to the project but still nothing

[Image Project Explorer and Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXYnc.png)

[GCC C++ Linker Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2aiX.png)

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Window *window;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
            "an SDL2 Window",
            20,
            20,
            640,
            480,
            SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Delay(3000);

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: How did what you try not work?  Did Eclipse delete your home directory?  Cause a kernel panic?

Comment: When ever I compile the program it comes back saying that SDL.h is missing or there is no such directory, even though i can see SDL in the includes from the project list.

When compiling i have tried using:
`gcc SDLTest.cpp`

Answer (score 2):

1. This will install everything necessary to build programs that use SDL: `sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev`
2. Create a new Eclipse project.
3. Go to properties of the project
4. C/C++ Build
5. Settings
6. GCC C++ Linker -> Libraries
7. Click on `Add...` and type `SDL2`
8. Apply and reindex the project

I used [this](http://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation#Linux.2FUnix) documentation. Tested with [SDL CreateWindow](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow).

Comment: I followed what you said. I was a bit unsure about "reindex"-ing the project,I assumed it was right-clicking the project going to index and using 'rebuild', "freshen all files" or "update with modified files", i did each one time. I then copied out that test code but my include for SDL is unresolved still. I have no idea what I've missed for it not to be working

Thanks again.

Comment: I followed the steps again, but I am still having the same problem, I linked another image showing where I added the `SDL2` just to make sure I am in the right place

Comment: When installing apt the include of sdl should be inside /usr/include, search inside the /usr/include the SDL2, and when you do the #include will be <SDL2/...>

Comment: In my /usr/include folder is a folder called SDL2 with SDL.h in it so that is in the right place? but the compiler and Eclipse are still not seeing it when I use `#include <SDL.h>`

Comment: it's in the right place, try to include it like this #include <SDL2/SDL.h>

Comment: I did that and it has fixed Eclipse saying it cannot find the include, but none of SDL's functions work, i updated the main post with my code to be sure its correct.

Comment: You linked the library? and re-indexed?

Comment: Yes and yes, Still had the same problem but I did `sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev` again. re-indexed again after that it worked I guess some of the files were corrupted or something. but following your steps on a new project worked fine now thanks a bunch